# Azure AD authentication for Airflow REST API

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, airflow

I have OAuth authentication with Azure Active Directory set up for Airflow and I was quite sure it also works for API and I can eg. trigger a DAG using a service principal.

But [API doc page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/security/api.html) says "*Authentication for the API is handled separately to the Web Authentication*" - what, why...? And while there are quite a lot of guides on how to setup authentication using Azure AD, all of them address UI only.

I was able to go through [this article](https://medium.com/@dany74q/service-to-service-auth-with-azure-ad-msi-oauth-2-0-step-by-step-a1aed196b1e1) and add application role assignment to my service principal - I think I'm good on Azure side.

Now in Airflow I probably need an [auth backend for API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/security/api.html#roll-your-own-api-authentication) to verify token sent with the request and read roles. Any hints here or an existing solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom_auth_backend to achieve this. There is one example on how to do it for Google OpenID.

[google_openid](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/common/auth_backend/google_openid.py)

You can refer it to create your own custom auth backend.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware I need an auth backend. I hoped there's an existing implementation for Azure though. I'm afraid I don't have enough OAuth-related knowledge to implement it by myself.